# "order by clauses" podem criar conflitos entre si?

Tags: sql, order-by

É possível que, se tivermos várias cláusulas no `order by`, estas entrem em conflito umas com as outras? Por exemplo:

```
select candidato.nome
from candidato, perfil_oferta, prova_de_afericao
where candidato.bi = prova_de_afericao.cod_prova and
prova_de_afericao.nr_identificacao = perfil_oferta.nr_identificacao and 
prova_de_afericao.classificacao > 
(select avg(prova_de_afericao.classificacao) from prova_de_afericao)
order by 
        perfil_oferta.nr_identificacao DESC, 
        prova_de_afericao.cod_prova DESC, 
        candidato.nome ASC;
```

O resultado não pode vir simultaneamente ordenado conforme as 3 cláusulas, por isso a minha pergunta é se há alguma prioridade associada às cláusulas, ou como é que estas se organizam se não for possível arranjar uma ordem que satisfaça as 3 cláusulas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi sua pergunta corretamente a resposta é não.

Na cláusula ORDER BY tem prioridade quem for definido primeiro.

Explicando utilizando seu exemplo:

O banco será ordenado utilizando o perfil_oferta.nr_identificacao descrescente.

Caso haja algum conflito no campo nr_identificacao, então esse conflito será resolvido ordennando o cod_prova, também descrescente.

Se houver conflito tanto em nr_identificacao e em cod_prova, então o último critério será utilizado para desempate.

Observe que as outras ordenações são apenas utilizadas quando houve "conflito", logo uma não irá influenciar a outra a ponto de entrar em conflito.

Caso tenha sobrado alguma dúvida, você pode consular no link a seguir (em inglês) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: Obrigada, o link foi útil, já esclareci a minha dúvida.

Comment: Sim, sua cláusula order by irá retornar exatamente assim.